# Spring MVC form - No items in dropdown list?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

My form has one `text field` and one `dropdown list`.When my form loads first time there is a `list of values in the dropdown list`.

If I am submitting the `form` , and my form has any `errors` , I am trying to return the same form to show the errors and to resubmit the missed data.

But if my form  `reloads` through the `POST` method of `controller` ,  there is no values in the dropdown list.

My **spring controller** ,

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    private ListStore getList;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ApplicationForm.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayForm(@ModelAttribute UserData userData,ModelMap map){

        map.addAttribute("age",(ArrayList<String>)getList.ageList());
        return "ApplicationForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ApplicaitonForm.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String displayFormDetails(@Valid UserData data,BindingResult result,ModelMap map,@RequestParam(value="name",required=true) String name,@RequestParam("age") String age){

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("It has some errors !!!!!!!!");
            return "ApplicationForm";
        }
        map.addAttribute("name", name);
        map.addAttribute("age", age);

        return "DisplayFormDetails";
    }
}
```

My **ListStore** class will be,

```
public class ListStore {

    public List<String> ageList(){
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("20 to 25 years");
        list.add("25 to 35 years");
        list.add("above 35 years");
        return list;
    }
 }
```

How to restore the values in the `dropdown` list , when my form reloads through the POST method of the controller ?

But I solved this issue  by adding  `map.addAttribute("age",(ArrayList<String>)getList.ageList());` as in my code as,

```
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Form has some errors !!!!!!!!");
        map.addAttribute("age",(ArrayList<String>)getList.ageList());
        return "ApplicationForm";
    }
```

But is there any other way to do this easily ?

Hope our stack members will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm usually calling display method from action (POST) method to avoid code duplication. See your slightly modified code below. I've also made small change in your code to follow [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    private ListStore getList;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ApplicationForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayForm(@ModelAttribute UserData userData, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("age", getList.ageList());
        return "ApplicationForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ApplicaitonForm.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid UserData data, 
                              BindingResult result, 
                              Model model, 
                              @RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name, 
                              @RequestParam("age") String age, 
                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("It has some errors !!!!!!!!");
            return displayForm(data, model); /* THIS IS THE TRICK :) */
        }

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("name", name);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("age", age);

        return "redirect:/DisplayFormDetails.html"; // Redirect here to follow Post/Redirect/Get pattern
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/DisplayFormDetails.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayFormDetails(Model model){
        // name and age are already in model due to use of RedirectAttributes
        return "DisplayFormDetails";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your code that ,

if your form has error then it is simply returning "ApplicationForm" view Name with no Model data exposed to view which view will display

```
  if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("It has some errors !!!!!!!!");
            return "ApplicationForm";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can co this working by once again adding the `map.addAttribute("age",(ArrayList<String>)getList.ageList());` , when I got any errors.

Comment: If it helped you and feel it as answer, Can you please accept solution.

Comment: I think all data in model attribute gets returned when you have errors and error message is displayed. So if you have many dropdown I think  you should try putting them into your user data and use that. Otherwise Jayesh's solution would work

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Autowired` annotation on getList property.

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @Autowired //annotation added
    private ListStore getList;
    -----
```

Comment: Hi , I already created a  bean for `Liststore` and injected in the controller through the `applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 0):

`@ModelAttribute` will help you.

```
@ModelAttribute
    public ModelMap setupForm(ModelMap modelMap) {

        modelMap.put("age",(ArrayList<String>)getList.ageList());
        return modelMap;
    }
```

[This is a nice article](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/spring-mvc-2-vs-spring-mvc-3-form-handling/) for understanding about handling Spring forms.